# Redirect to login page when lost connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to redirect to login page if there any network issue or service down happen. I done a code which is redirect to login page. The problem is it redirect only the body. The layout is still there I want to show complete login page.  Meaning I need to remove the layout. I have tried using `window.location.href` however I would like to use `res.redirect('/');`

```
> var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    var now = moment();

// logger.error("Tracing here", {"name":"routeshandler.js", "operation" : "isAuthenticated" });

// if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
// Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
// request and response objects

if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    if (req.user && global.users[req.user.userid]) {
        global.users[req.user.userid].lastactive = now;
    }

    return next();
}

req.logout();
// if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
res.redirect('/');
res.end();
```

}

But it is load only the body. the layout is still  there. How can I reload the complete page?